# Insert into table cannot be done PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I want to insert values into a database table but for some reason it cannot be done.I checked the code millions of times but it is impossible to find what goes wrong.If anyone could have a look..

```
if($_POST['opt1'] == 'add') {
    $stmt_insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customer (card, store, points, comments) VALUES (:card_number, :store, :points, :comments)");

    $stmt_insert->bindParam(':card_number', $_SESSION['card']);
    $stmt_insert->bindParam(':store', $_SESSION['store']);
    $stmt_insert->bindParam(':points', $_POST['points']);
    $stmt_insert->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments']);
    $stmt_insert->execute();

    header("Location:index.php");
}
else if($_POST['opt1'] == 'remove') {
    $stmt_insert2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customer (card, store, points, comments) VALUES (:card_number, :store, :points, :comments)");

    $stmt_insert2->bindParam(':card_number', $_SESSION['card']);
    $stmt_insert2->bindParam(':store', $_SESSION['store']);
    $stmt_insert2->bindParam(':points', $_POST['points']);
    $stmt_insert2->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments']);
    $stmt_insert2->execute();

    header("Location:index.php");     
}
```

Database connect :

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = "root";
$password = "1234";
$db = "customers";

try {
    //Creating connection for mysql
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Form Code :

```
<form name="pontoi" action="update.php" method="post">

              <div class="input-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Σχόλια Συναλλαγής:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text"  name="comments" class="form-control">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                             </div>


           <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
               <div class="row">

                  <br>


                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="i-checks">
                        <label class="radio-inline">ΠΡΟΣΘΗΚΗ
                            <input type="radio" value="add" name="opt1" checked="">
                        </label></div>
                        </div>




                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="i-checks">
                        <label class="radio-inline">ΕΞΑΡΓΥΡΩΣΗ
                            <input type="radio" value="remove" name="opt1">
                        </label></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  maxlength="3" name="points"> <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                                    <button type="submit" onclick="return checkInp()" class="btn btn-primary">Go
                                    </button> </span></div>

                            </div>
                            </form>
```

Form Post Data

```
Array ( [comments] => Antiliaka [points] => 50 )
```

Comment: We need a bit more info. Show where you connect to the database!

Comment: what error occurs can you please tell? please give more detail

Comment: is anything displayed with `ini_set('error_reporting', -1);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` or after `stmt_insert2->execute();` calling `print_r($conn->errorInfo());` It may be that `isset($_POST['opt1']);` is false or does not equal `add` or `remove`

Comment: May be code not enter into both condition!! Post your form code too!!

Comment: Are there fields you are neglecting to insert, but are `NOT NULL` fields such as customer_name or customer_id? Or are you actually trying to insert new values into a customer row that is already in the database? Wondering why you have an insert for `$_POST['opt1'] == 'remove'`.

Comment: How is your customer table defined?

Comment: Can you put your `stmt_insert` lines in a try ... catch and show the except ?                 `catch ( Exception $e ) 
                    {
                    echo 'There was an error in "prog.php"<br />';
                    echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
                    echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
                    exit();
                    }`

Comment: Have you forget to `session_start()` on the top of your page???

Comment: All the fields have value NULL as default.Is this a problem?I have created the table customer in the customers database and this table is empty and structured of course.I have two radio buttons..

Comment: Post your form code too!!

Comment: When I submit the form, the result page is nothing only a white page.I echoed values like $_POST['store'] and it appeared in the page..

Comment: okk just post value of `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_SESSION) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and see if you receive an error message at all.

```
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

if(isset($_POST['opt1']) && ($_POST['opt1'] == 'add' || $_POST['opt1'] == 'remove')){
    try{
        if(!$stmt_insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customer (card, store, points, comments) VALUES (:card_number, :store, :points, :comments)")){
            print_r($conn->errorInfo());
            die('Invalid Query');
        }

        $stmt_insert->bindParam(':card_number', $_SESSION['card']);
        $stmt_insert->bindParam(':store', $_SESSION['store']);
        $stmt_insert->bindParam(':points', $_POST['points']);
        $stmt_insert->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments']);
        if (!$stmt_insert->execute()) {
            print_r($sth->errorInfo());
            exit;
        }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       exit;
    }
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
} else {
   die('Invalid Option Specified ' . $_POST['opt1']);
}
```

**Updated**

Try changing your form radio button.

`<input type="radio" value="add" name="opt1" checked="checked">`

Also Try changing the submit button to be an input element.

`<input name="test" type="submit" onclick="return checkInp()" class="btn btn-primary" value="go">`

Comment: The message that appeared is : Invalid Option Specified

Comment: That means that your `$_POST['opt1']` is empty. Since it is set to display the value of `$_POST['opt1']`. So it is never executing the SQL statements

Comment: Validate the `$_POST` data by calling `print_r($_POST);` at the top of the script.

Comment: `Array ( [comments] => Antiliaka [points] => 50 ) ` That means that something goes wrong with the radio buttons..I can't understand what really goes wrong.They are inside the form.So what else I have to check to be sure that I pass values through $_POST global variable??

Comment: Perhaps something wrong in javascript, what's in the `checkInp()` javascript function. It may be removing the `opt1` values.

Comment: this is the function `var x=document.forms["pontoi"]["points"].value;
              var y=200;
              if (x>y) 
              {
               window.confirm("ΠΡΟΣΟΧΗ! Ο αριθμός πόντων που θέλετε να εισάγετε ίσως ειναι αρκετά μεγάλος. Θέλετε να συνεχίσετε?");
                return false;
              }` but I don't think this is the real problem..

Comment: Correct, that just shows a confirmation box when the submitted points is over 200, but should `return window.confirm(...)` to ensure the form is submitted if the user clicks ok, or stops submission if the user clicks cancel.

Comment: That is with changing the `button` to an `input` element with `value="Go"`? If so add a `name="test"` to the `input type="submit"` element.

Comment: It worked!I made some tests in the code you posted and I managed to pass data rows into the table!Don't ask me how..hahaha!Thanks man!I owe you!

Comment: `</div> <div class="ibox float-e-margins">` this piece of code was the **REAL** problem!!!!!.If you check the form_code in the line 9 - 13 or something..Thanks again man!

Comment: Yep, np, invalid markup is always difficult to troubleshoot without a validator. I suggest using an editor that can perform additional syntax validation like PHPStorm, or manually checking the resulting page source using the W3C validator. https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Ok I will check this out!Regards!